# Creating a code review automated workflow

Tags: java, svn, automation, sonarqube

On doing some research wrt to code review tools, I found the working of `Gerrit` with `GIT`. Developers push their changes which then resides on Gerrit repository for review. Once review is approved, the changes are finally pushed to git repo.

I am using `svn` in my project with `sonarQube` as the code review tool. But, usually we run the sonarqube when required. Point here is there is no automation of code review. Thus, we don't allow all developers with commit access. They send the patches to the concerned lead, who is reviewing and then committing.

I am looking for ways to automate this whole process and make it more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the Upsource from jetbrains
https://www.jetbrains.com/upsource/